# Сложный цикл for

Tags: c#, c++

Мне нужно реализовать один отдельный цикл, он должен быть примерно такой

```
 int i = 0

 int c = 10

 T1 = <

 T2 = ++

    for (; i T1 c; i T2)
    {
        cout << i << " i " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n" << endl;
    }
```

Мне интересно, возможно ли T1 и T2 сделать оператором <, ++, -- или *

Изменить операторы ++ на -- вносить их в переменные или что то с ними делать.

Еще вариант такой, возможно как то добавить условия

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>

auto test(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c, T4 x)
{
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;



    for (; a c b; a x)
    {
        cout << a << " |a " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n" << endl;
    }

}



//test(2.242, <, 20, ++);
```

Comment: Вставьте тернарное выражение в T2. T1 - можно написать не равно.

Comment: `for (; i != c; i += ((i>c)? -1:1)  )`

Comment: Лучше задать отдельно вопросы по C# и C++.

Comment: for (; i != c; i += ((i>c)? -1:1) )
Как то сложно выглядит не понимаю как работает

Comment: В с# нужно писать явно - нельзя T1 T2. В с++ можно воспользоваться макросами. Если хочется именно T1 T2

Comment: Читайте в справке к языку - 1)тернарный оператор. 2) оператор `!=`

Comment: T1 и T2 это как пример я сделал типо test1 и test2

Comment: Все больше вариантов нету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И в с++ и в с# можно записать так

```
for (; i != c; i += ((i>c)? -1:1) ) {
   }
```

Где операцию `++` `--` можно задать как `i = i + 1` и `i + i + (-1);` благодаря тернарному оператору. `(условие)?если_да:если_нет`. В даном случае условие `i>c` - если i больше с будет прибавлятся -1, иначе +1.

В с++ можно сделать макрос (#define для T1 T2) и сделать файл с циклом:

```
  for (; i T1 c; i T2)
   {
    // ...
   }
```

с макросами тяжелее будет что-то менять. Но выкрутится можно так - файл_с_циклом.с

```
 if (i < c) {
  #define T1 >
  #define T2 ++
  #include "файл_с_циклом.с"
  #undef T1
  #undef T2
    } else {
  #define T1 <
  #define T2 --
  #include "файл_с_циклом.с"
  #undef T1
  #undef T2
  }
```

Макросом же можно даже спаковать это в один файл. Типа так (итог)

```
 #ifndef T1
    // Основная программа

 if (i < c) {
  #define T1 >
  #define T2 ++
  #include "файл_с_циклом.h"
  #undef T1
  #undef T2
    } else {
  #define T1 <
  #define T2 --
  #include "файл_с_циклом.h"
  #undef T1
  #undef T2
  }
 // Продолжение
 #else
    for (; i T1 c; i T2){
    cout << i << " i " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n" << endl;
}
 #endif
```

Comment: Получается что мне нужно делать что бы изменять ++ на -- ?

Comment: Записать в тернарном операторе условие.

Comment: Макрос наверно не сможет работать с шаблоном template

Comment: попробовал подключить макрос T2 в цикл а он получается такого вида iT2 если делать слитно он не сработает, а если раздельно, будет думать что это i ++ а не i++

Думаю макросы это уже очень извращенный вариант программирования)

Comment: `i++` и `i ++` будут собраны одинаково. А то что вы предлагаете и есть извращенное предложение))))

Comment: Ну я думал тут есть какие то лютые штуки что бы делать очень крутые шаблоны с операторами )

Comment: Например соединив все с многопоточным программированиям не придется создавать множество циклов, а только указания на операторы.

Comment: Ну - максимум - можно вот так пошутить))))

Comment: Я думаю за такой код могут застрелить в переулке)))

Comment: `((i>c)? -1:1` - лучше бы в переменную вынести шаг цикла?

Answer (score 3):

*C#*

```
  Func<int, bool> T1 = iter => iter < 100;
  Func<int, int> T2 = iter => iter + 1;

  int i = 0;
  for (; T1(i); i = T2(i))
  {
  }
```

Comment: Это вообще чет сверх извращенное)

Comment: Мне кажется за такое программисты убить могут

Comment: @chip Это в точности ответ на Ваш вопрос. Вам понадобится приложить некоторые умственные усилия, чтобы его понять.

Comment: Я пробую на С++ поэтому на С# не могу попробовать что бы понять, к сожалению.

Comment: @chip - так нафига в тегах стоит C#?

Comment: Ну языки похоже просто и обычно программисты владеют двумя С# и C++

Comment: @chip `обычно программисты владеют двумя С# и C++` - спорное утверждение :)

Comment: @chip Очень спорное. На будущее - не надо ставить теги по такому принципу. На каком языке хотите ответ, такой тег и ставьте.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Мне на любом из двух языков норм, но ответы очень печальные сейчас. Самый нормальный с макросами пока что.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto t = [](int i) { return i < 1000; };
int di = -1;

for (int i=0; t(i); i+=di)
  ...
```

Comment: пока не получается нормально запустить, цикл постоянно работает

Comment: @chip, ну вообще-то логично, что цикл `for (int i=0; i<1000; --i)` бесконечный. Я просто идею показал.